# how to call procedure in database asynchronously from java 1.4 code?

Tags: asynchronous, sql-server-2000, ejb-3.0, procedure, java1.4

platform:
Sql server 2000
java 1.4
ejb 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to get the question but calling a stored procedure involves using a [`CallableStatement`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html). For the asynchronous part, and because you mentioned EJBs, the standard way would be to use JMS and a Message Driven Bean. But I'm a bit confused by the part where you mention Java 1.4 and EJB 3.0 (that requires Java 1.5). Maybe you should clarify that requirement. Sending JMS messages to a MDB 3.0 from a Java 1.4 client should be possible though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find a way to handle this at database level, you can do it like you would do any asynchronous stuff:

```
thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // do your procedure call here
    }
};
thread.start();
```